# MySQL selection / JOIN on four tables results in time-out

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I need to do a selection on 4 tables. Combining table ships and table ship_history is no problem, I get the results instantly. I tried with a normal select and a LEFT JOIN, both are instant. When I try to LEFT JOIN the third table, it takes a very long time (timeouts occurs most of the time). And I would like to even join a fourth table.

All four tables are connected with the ID from table ships. For the table ship_construction I only need the records where column final equals to 1. This is my current query for 3 tables:

```
SELECT s.id
     , s.name
     , s.year
     , s.built
     , sh.col_1
     , sh.col_2
     , sh.col_3
     , sc.col_1
     , sc.col_2
     , sc.final 
  FROM ships s
  LEFT 
  JOIN ship_history sh
    ON sh.ship_id = s.id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN ship_construction sc
    ON sc.ship_id = s.id 
   AND sc.final = 1
```

For every record in table ships there is one record in the ship_history table. For tables 3 and 4 this can be zero or more for every table 1 record. I used a LEFT JOIN, because I need all records from table 1.

Table ships currently has 17128 records
Table ship_history currently has 17128 records
Table ship_construction currently has 41935 records
Table 4 currently has 57988 records

Of course I already read tons of Stackoverflow topics and searched (and searched and searched) on Google. I have tried many different approaches, but I think I am on the wrong track. I also read about indexes, but this is new for me so I am not sure if this is necessary in this case.

Could anyone push me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated, if additional info is needed just let me know.

**Just for the record: my current query DOES work, but it takes too long.**

Thanks

Comment: Have you added correct indexes? Try adding indexes on ships.id (if it isnt a PRIMARY KEY) and to (`ship_construction`.`ship_id` + `ship_construction`.`final`)..
ALTER TABLE `ship_construction` 
ADD INDEX `idx_ships_constr`(`ship_id`, `final`) USING BTREE;

Comment: I think you were in the right direction with indexes. Indexes should help you do the job much faster, read more about it

Comment: Thanks for the both of you! @Firewizz: I added your index and my query is now giving an instant result! What a difference :D Now I need to figure out how to join the fourth table :-)